# React Native Scrollview with flexGrow doesn't scroll

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-native-scrollview

I am using scrollview in my react native project. But it is not scrollable  ie, i cant see the top elements . when i scroll to bottom the view bounces back.My requirement is actually like this

1) Bottom item should be visible -----> It is working fine now

2) while scrolling top item should be visible should not bounces back the view -----> Now this is the issue

Here is my code

```
return (
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
    <View style={styles.main}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        ........(Some code)
      </View>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: "#fff",
alignItems: "center",
justifyContent: "flex-end",
padding: 6,
paddingTop: 250
},
main: {
flex: 1,
height: 100
}
});
```

Any idea what am I missing ? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The problem could be that `height: 100`. Why use it when it has `flex: 1` (by default `flexDirection: 'column'`)?

Comment: May add your reproducible issue in https://snack.expo.io? This will be easy to debug.

Comment: @SubhenduKundu please check this... https://snack.expo.io/H1BQaVWL4

Comment: @Milore without height: 100 its not working.

Comment: I'll take a look at your snack

Comment: I tried to apply what I wrote as answer and it seems to work properly. Can you check if it's what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment, the problem could be that `height: 100` used with `flex: 1` (in fact `flexDirection` is `column` by default, so you're trying to set height in two different ways). Since seems there's no reason to have it, simply remove it. In order to keep your `ScrollView` scrolled at the bottom I suggest you to do something like:

```
  <ScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
    ref={ref => (this.scrollView = ref)}
    onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
      this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({ animated: true });
    }}
  > ...
```

I've created a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@milore/supportive-croissant) which tries to reproduce your question. Take a look if you want!